# Slow Performance Custom Script GAS

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

So, I've written (for lack of answers + improving my skills) a search script that would do basically what .indexOf does.

```
function search(ref, data) {

  var x
  var y
  var result = []

  if (data == '' || data == null) {
  } else {
    for (x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
      if (data[x] == ref[0]) {                //achando match inicial
        var proto = [];
        for (y = 0; y < ref.length; y++) {
          if (data[x+y] == ref[y]) {          //gravando tentativas de match completo
          proto.push(data[x+y])
          }
        }
        var proto2 = proto.join('')
        if (proto2 == ref) {                   //testando match completo
            result.push(x)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (result == '' || result == null) {
  } else {
    return result[0]
  }
}
```

It works fine within other little codes and custom functions that do not require too much looping, but when I wrote a more robust script I found that my code is roughly 3000x slower than the native .indeOf.

Why would I incur in such a difference?

Comment: "lack of answers" to what question?

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, about `I found that my code is roughly 3000x slower than the native .indeOf.`, can you provide the compared script and the sample input and output values for replicating `roughly 3000x slower`?

Comment: Rùben, I did not actually run a comparative worth replicating, mostly because of my lack of testing knowledge - and also because of the disparity of results. I'm mostly looking for insight into the inner engines from GAS as to why native codes would run faster than even those simples scripts. In any case, I'll run a structured comparison and share the results later.

Comment: Also, "lack of answers" was related to search string methods (such as .indexOf or .contains) native to GAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

Your function is comparing each character from `ref` separately with a `data` character, in an inner loop, pushing each character match inside an array (`proto`) and using `join` to transform the array back to a string (`proto2`), before comparing it to the original `ref`.

This is extremely inefficient and could be greatly simplified, so no question this function is much slower than [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

#### Solution:

You could have a single loop instead, iterating through `data`, and for each iteration, retrieve a [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) of `data` with the same length as `ref`, before comparing this slice with `ref`. If both values match, the string `ref` has been found in `data`, and the corresponding index is returned:

```js
function searchString(ref, data) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= data.length - ref.length; i++) {
    if (ref === data.slice(i, i + ref.length)) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

While using this function, I get similar execution times than with `indexOf`.

#### Reference:

- [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [String.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: Thanks! I greatly appreciate your solution, that's definetely way simpler than my original code.